# How to set a Common type for Callable

Tags: java, generics

I want to implement a super class and it is a `java.util.concurrent.Callable` . The child class will return different types of objects for `Callable`. Therefore, I want set this super class callable's generic type as to be any type. Following is my super class declaration.

```
public abstract class AbsTaskRunner implements java.util.concurrent.Callable {
```

I want to set generic type of Callable as any type.

```
 public abstract class AbsTaskRunner implements java.util.concurrent.Callable <HERE_COMMON_TYPE> {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
public abstract class AbsTaskRunner<T> implements java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>
```

Then the sub-classes can be *either* generic (like this):

```
public class GenericSubclass<T> extends AbsTaskRunner<T>
```

*or* extend `AbsTaskRunner` for some specific type (like this):

```
public class StringSubclass extends AbsTaskRunner<String>
```

Comment: THIS WOKRED>> THANKS VERY MUCH.